# Geometry Nodes - how to group Face Corners with common Vertex for group max Attribute filtering

Tags: geometry-nodes

First I calculate Curvature float value for every face corner of mesh.

Than I want to use "FindGroupmax" node group from lukas_t to find max curvature value for every Vertex based on its Face Corners.

Im not sure how to sort/group Face Corners with "common" Vertex (sharing same location).

Perhaps something with "corners of vertex" node? Or something with comparing positions?

Here is the example file

[image]

- this is how curvature values look displayed on face corners (looks ok-ish)

[image]

- this is after (wrong) filtering, it is scrambled all over the place becouse of wrong use of indicies.

[image]

- this is node tree with highlighted grouping issue

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get a *group ID* fir all the corners of a vertex, all you have to do is use the vertex index.

So you use an *evaluate on domain* node set to vertices. (Or the *vertex of corner* node, they are the same thing).

Comment: Thanks to your tip I've made some progress, although not quite there. If I store Index (point) before calc. the curvature and use that as group ID fo "FindGroupMax", together with interpolate (evaluate) Domain in front of that, the values get smoothed-out, which is something. However the "FindGroupMax" is not doing anything (I know it works when plugged in correctly). Any idea what could be wrong now?
https://ibb.co/K9gs6mz

Comment: You setup doesn't really make so much sense. In a grid there are usually 4 corners per vertex except on the corners. You only use two corners and they are probably not from the same vertex since you are kinda doing it wrong. You probably want to offset the index after you set the corner index not beforehand.  We also don't know what the nodegroup findgroupmax dose. So there could be a lor of issues. As well this could just not do what you were expecting.